# Silverlight and RIA Services - The Data sources window does not show anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

So following some of the examples out there I created a new Silverlight Navigation application with RIA services enabled. Built the entity model, added a domain service
and tested whether or not I could get some data to the client. This works fine.

But many of the examples show off how they use the Data Sources window
to simply drag data fields onto a window... in my case however there are no data sources in the data sources window.

In the demo's and mix sessions this just appears out of the blue :p
Anyway how can I get my DomainService defined in the web project to show up
as one of the data sources in the data sources window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in the previous versions with the following workaround:

http://blogs.msdn.com/vsdata/archive/2010/04/13/workaround-to-data-source-window-not-populating-ria-services-domain-context-objects.aspx

Basically this happened when you installed VS2010 on any drive other than c:\

The issue has been resolved in Ria Services 1.0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the new Release Candidate of VS2010 and Silverlight?

Also, the data sources view will only work when you are on a XAML page in the main editor window.

Comment: Yep, the RC1 with the latest hotfix , silverlight tools
and I'm in the right place